# I create trace.html using android Systrace tool, chrome cannot open it

Tags: android, google-chrome, systrace

I use chrome to open trace.html generated by android device monitor, It shows blank. How can I set my chrome?

Answer (score 4):

1. Open `Android Device Monitor` from menu `Tools > Android > Android Device Monitor`

and `drag and drop` your file to that window.

2. Open Chrome and enter `chrome://tracing/` in URL and press enter > load `your stacktrace file` by clicking `Load` option at top

That's it.

Comment: you tried both the options? and is your chrome updated?

Comment: Hi Er. Kaushik Kajavadara ： I tried the option 2， still meet some problem，it shows “There was an error while importing the traceData: Could not find an importer for the provided eventData.”。Looking forward to and thanks for your reply！

Comment: chrome://tracing is ok for me